# Table not resizing to 100% vertically?

Tags: html, css

I have a quick problem for you guys. I'm still learning HTML, but I'm working on a personal page and want boxes spread out across the entire window, no matter how big or small the window is. It works great when I do it horizontally, but never works vertically. It just stays in a standard format downwards.

## My Code

### HTML:

```
<table class="table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### CSS:

```
.table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: central;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not resizing because setting `table { height:100%; }` is just telling it to fill 100% of its parent. You will need to set your `html` and `body` to `height:100%`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/tRq2r/)

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
}

.table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: central;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Is your body and html selectors are have 100% of height? If not, extend your stylesheet with this:

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `height: 100% !important;` perhaps this will make it work.